# remove parents directory period from out put- php

Tags: php

How can I remove the parent directory period(.) from the output because I need to add the result (filename, filesize etc)in the database. What would be the best way to display it without the dots. I am new to php really spending time to learn as much as soon.

**Code:**

```
<?PHP

    $dirname     = "C:/folder1/folder2/ftpfiles/";

    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $connection = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    if (!$connection)
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('dbname', $connection);

    if (is_dir($dirname)) {

        if ($dh = opendir($dirname)) {

            while (!(($file = readdir($dh)) === false)) {
                echo $file . " ";                
                foreach (glob("$dirname/*.csv") as $files) {
                    $filesize = filesize($files);
                    $filetime = filemtime($files);
                    $filename = strstr($file, '-', true);
                }


                echo $filename . " ";
                echo $filesize . " ";
                echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $filetime) . "\n\n";

                $importSQL = "INSERT INTO tableVALUES('".$filename."','".$file."','".$filesize."','".$date."')";
                mysql_query($importSQL) or die(mysql_error());
            }
            closedir($dh);
            mysql_close($connection);
        }
    } else
        echo "No File Exists";
?>
```

**Output:**

[image: output - Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep things simple. Simply make sure to ignore those two "special entries" in the folder listing:

```
<?php
// ...
if (is_dir($dirname)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dirname)) {
        while (!(($file = readdir($dh)) === false)) {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe more elegant and robust would be to ignore all folders, since your code inside the `while` loop relies on the fact that all entries actually are files, not folders themselves:

```
<?php
// ...
if (is_dir($dirname)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dirname)) {
        while (!(($file = readdir($dh)) === false)) {
            if (!is_dir($file)) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that was not meant in a literal way. I know programming is a serious task, but hey... :-)